# Plans to travel to China, but recognized as a USA-China dual citizen? Any issues?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, china, dual-nationality, chinese-citizens

I am 26 years old, US citizen (born and raised), have never been to China but planning on going this year. My parents were Chinese nationals at the time I was born so I am considered a Chinese national according to their law. I am only finding this out now as I was told I need a travel document, and not a visa to travel to China. My only concern is, will I have issues when exiting China since I am also considered a Chinese national? Is there anything else I need to know? I have a US passport and nothing else, just want to do my research before I go. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you haven’t already committed _some_ crime under Chinese law? If you are a male person you _had_ to serve the military – the PLA – as a Chinese national, although to be fair an obligatory pledge of allegiance would be pretty worthless given your background. I don’t know the details how such a case is handled.

Answer (score 8):

> My parents were Chinese nationals at the time I was born so I am considered a Chinese national according to their law.

Check again if either of your parents were permanent residents of the U.S. at the time of your birth. If either had green card, you are not a Chinese national.

> My only concern is, will I have issues when exiting China since I am also considered a Chinese national?

Normally, your Chinese travel document, if issued for two years, is valid for exit and entry, unless otherwise endorsed. This (being in "conflict of nationalities", where a Chinese national involuntarily acquires another nationality by law of another country) is no longer something that unusual.

As a Chinese citizen, you are not entitled to U.S. consular protection while in China*, though as a U.S. citizen, you can and should still ask U.S. embassy for help if incidents arise. You should still bring your U.S. passport; if nothing else, the airlines need your American passport to allow you to board the plane to the U.S.

[*] Exception exists for persons who are considered to be Chinese citizens, but entered China with a U.S. passport and an apparently valid Chinese visa (despite that the visa should not have been issued to a Chinese national). These persons are entitled to U.S. consular assistance under a bilateral agreement between the U.S. and China. Persons who travel on a Chinese travel document is considered as Chinese citizens only within China and cannot claim right to consular protection.

Comment: Thanks for your response. No my parents were not permanent residents of the U.S at the time of my birth, so I would fall under a Chinese national. I was reading that you are supposed to select a nationality or renounce it when you turn 18, however I am 26 and just learning about this.  I am going to apply for the travel document, but is renouncing my chinese citizenship something I still have to do or can I just forget about it?

Comment: @myu Although the law never changed, the past practice was indeed to ask you to renounce it; however, the practice has now gradually changing to recognize the Chinese nationaly of people with "conflicting" nationalities. You still have the option to renounce it, if you wish to do so.

Comment: Thank you very much, i appreciate your help and response in this matter

Comment: Basically, applying for the Travel Document will be the litmus test: if they issue it to you, the PRC considers you to be a Chinese citizen. If they refuse, you're not. And if they do, make sure you get the 2-year document.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "U.S. consular protection while in China"? Does this apply to all U.S. Citizens who visit China?

Comment: @Anemoia , a Chinese - Lilliputian citizen who visits China is a considered to be Chinese citizen by the Chinese authorities even if they used their Lilliputian passport to enter China. They are not allowed protection / assistance of the Lilliputian government.     If the Lilliputian citizen is not also a Chinese citizen and visit China, then they are allowed Lilliputian  protection / assistance

Comment: @Anemoia In general, when in country A, a citizen of A is considered only as the citizen of A and does not have the right to receive consular assistance from country B even if they are also citizen of B, see e.g. https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/mohamed-fahmy-case-dual-citizenship-can-complicate-diplomatic-protection-1.2684357 Country B generally would still try to help, but their ability to assert consular rights and privileges are limited under intl law.

Comment: @Anemoia U.S. citizens who are not citizens of China can assert right to consular assistance and protection in China. Furthermore, pursuant to a bilateral agreement, persons who entered China using a U.S. passport and a Chinese visa are entitled to U.S. consular protection even if China claims that the person is also a Chinese citizen; as such, Chinese consulates will try to ascertain your lack of Chinese nationality before issuing you a visa.